# NodeJS API - Broker Service Pattern to cause internal API redirection

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

We are currently working on a nodejs application which hosts API's (includes both get and post HTTP methods). These server API's in nodejs server are individually accessible or allowed to be called. Like /api/login (login api) is allowed to be called directly from clients.

Next, I want to introduce a service broker API which should be entry point to all API calls from client side. So, any client calling a specific API such as /api/login should go through service broker and then service broker should re-direct to requested API based on the specific service details as sent by clients.

Thereby, all clients should only be able to call only one API (i.e. broker service API - /broker/service). So, all requests from clients should first hit service broker API and then service broker should redirect to appropriate API's based on the input parameters passed to service broker from clients. Input parameters could contain the API URL and input data.

Currently, I'm able to connect directly to individual API's from clients. But, now I would like to introduce a new layer namely service broker and that broker service should decide which API the request should be redirected along with input data (sent from clients).

Note: Both broker service API and other functionality specific API's are hosted under same domain. So, there will not be any CORS issue. We are using "express" node module for handling HTTP API requests.

- My initial question is whether this requirement can be achieved?
- If yes, then can we perform internal redirection of API's in node server?
- Can this be achieved with express node module?

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: It probably can be achieved, yes. Internal redirects might be a bit hard. I imagine you could do this with middle-ware in Express. But the question is - why would you want to just have clients use one endpoint and then internally redirect them? It seems like what you have now works, and what you want adds nothing beneficial, onlyt more logic and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to go this route, you could do something like this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  the_route_passed = req.originalUrl;
  //handle all of the routes here in your api function call.
});
```

What this will do is for every single route passed from the front-end will go through your function, and then you can grab the route that was passed `req.originalUrl` will be like `/api/users/230` for user 230.  Then you'll need to parse the route or however you want to do it and pass it through to your service broker.

This would be the best way to deal with not having to change anything on the front-end if  you are already using Routing.  The other way which might be better in the long run:

Send JSON on each request and configure it however you want, and then when you receive it you can figure out all the routing from the JSON request on each go.  You'd have to rewrite all routes on the front-end to do this though which might be too much work.